# Override particular range of code points with a non-default font

Tags: fonts

Is it possible to override glyphs at some range of code points, that the default-font already covers, with ones from a non-default font?

For instance, I'd like to use *Arial* only except for the uppercase letters, which I want to use *Cooper Black* for. How can I achieve this?

I know that I can override some rage of code points whose glyphs are **missing** in the default font, but I'm failing to do the same for the code points whose glyphs exist in the default font.

Here's what I tested.

```
(set-face-attribute 'default nil :family "Arial")
(let (
(my-upper-case-font "Cooper Black")
(font-sets '(
               "fontset-default"
               "fontset-standard"
               "fontset-startup")))
(mapcar
(lambda (font-set)

(set-fontset-font font-set '(#x00. #x17F) my-upper-case-font)
;I set the range wider for the sake of testing. 
;This doesn't work and when I inserted "t" after "font-set", 
;a message showed up saying "Wrong type argument: frame-live-p, "Cooper Black""
)
font-sets))
```

Answer (score 1):

See this question I asked: [Override the default font for emoji characters](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/62049/override-the-default-font-for-emoji-characters). The gist of it is that *you have to set* `use-default-font-for-symbols` *to nil to make Emacs honor the fontsets*. Then you can specify the fontsets themselves, which can be simply

```
(set-fontset-font t '(#x00. #x17F) my-upper-case-font)
```

See also [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Modifying-Fontsets.html) and ["best practice" for configuring fonts in Emacs today - fontsets, the default face, and ... IDK, like, stabbing things, maybe?](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/9l3n3y/best_practice_for_configuring_fonts_in_emacs/) on Reddit (Eli Zaretskii, one of Emacs' maintainers, posted some tips there).