Can I set color for a unicode range?
I'd like to be able to set the background color on different Unicode ranges.
For example:

This is some  .

might become something like:
This is some  .
I've seen that it's possible to override the font, per range, as described here:
https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/62055/8406
But can I specify the face to use, per font?

As commented by db45x, Font Lock is indeed the answer here.  The only challenge in that Font Lock needs word boundaries, not just arbitrary character strings.  Slightly tricky; setting up keyword lists like this works:
(setq letters1  (concat "\\<" (regexp-opt '("")  t) 
"[]*\\>" ))


You need to read chapter 15.13 Font Lock mode of the Emacs manual. Note that you can also use C-h i to read this manual without leaving Emacs.

Naturally I looked at Font Lock, I just needed to find one particular feature of it.
